# Would it be considered ethical for two brothers to work as executives at competing public companies?

Tags: business

Let's say Bruce is CFO at Exxon Mobil and his brother Clark works under the CTO at BP.

Considering possible implications of the fact that these brothers are expected as siblings to have a reasonably close relationship, would this scenario be considered strange, unethical and/or illegal?

Comment: Ethics are not typically a relevant matter for law.

Comment: @Nij The question isn't really about ethics, it's more about law. Obviously, it can't be illegal for siblings to be executives of competing companies, but it's likely to set up problems that I don't know about, hence the question. The question is about what would most likely happen in legal proceedings and views of this situation going forward, which would be a debate of ethics.

Comment: The title says "would it be considered unethical..." and the body leads its problem statement with "... strange, unethical or...". And *what happens next* as a legal question doesn't care much if at all, about an ethics debate; that ethics debate is off-topic here and doesn't require mentioning at all, or should be ignored entirely.